# Using ansible variables in when statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm using ansible_hostname variable in when statement to find string containing it in command stdout like this:

```
when: result.stdout.find("some stdout text {{ansible_hostname}}") == -1
```

or

```
when: result.stdout.find("some stdout text {{ansible_hostname}}") != -1
```

and my tasks work as expected but ansible throws out warning about using jinja2 template in when statement:

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}
```

So what is the correct way to pass ansible_hostname inside a string to find in stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Next option would be to use this condition

```
when: "'some stdout text ' ~ ansible_hostname in result.stdout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like:

```
when: result.stdout.find('some stdout text ' ~ ansible_hostname) == -1
```